# Proving the degree of the antipodal circle function.

Tags: general-topology, circles

I was asked to determine the degree of the antipodal circle function  $f(\theta)=\theta + \pi$.
I believe the degree of the function is $1$, through pictures and illustration, but I will like to prove this using homotopy.

So given our degree $1$ map $C_{-1}(\theta):S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is given by $$f(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$.

Could I use as a homotopy $H(x,t)=(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))e^{t\pi i} $. 
If so how will prove it is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, you can simplify your formula by writing 
$$H(z,t) = z\cdot e^{\pi i t} .$$
Note that $S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \lvert z  \rvert =  1\}$. The map $H$ is continuous because complex multiplication is continuous and the exponential function is continuous.

If you want you can also write $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 =  1\}$ and 
$$H(x,y,t) = (x\cos(\pi t) - y \sin(\pi t), x \sin(\pi t) + y \cos(\pi t)) .$$

Comment: Thank you but this does not prove our function is continuous. The space $ S^1\times[0,1]$ im not sure if it a metric space. Hence, what are you usig to prove that our function is continuous. I beloeve we need an intermediate function.

Comment: It does prove it, but it takes for granted a few well-known facts. I am not going to give proofs. 1) The function $[0,1] \to \mathbb C, t \mapsto \pi i t$, is continuous. This is trivial, multiplication with the constant $c = \pi i$ is continuous. 2) The function $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C, w \to e^{iw}$, is continuous. Complex multiplication $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, (z_1,z_2) \mapsto z_1 \cdot z_2$, is continuous.

Comment: Wouln't we also need that that  if  the function $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $[0,1] \rightarrrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous. Then $\mathbb{C} \times  \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ is continuous. I know a lot steps, I just need my proofs alwas to be true.

Comment: @benhuni Yes, you are right. We need the fact that "product maps" (here $\mathbb C \times [0,1] \to \mathbb C \times \mathbb C$) are continuous. This is true for all pairs of maps between metric (or more generally  topological) spaces. By the way, you can also an $\epsilon$-$\delta$-argument to show directly the $H(x,y,t)$ is continuous.

Comment: ahh! I see now thanks!